# Unicode character replication MSSQL to MYSQL in Symmetric DS

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, mysql-5.6, character-set, unicode

I'm doing replication from MSSQL to MYSQL using symmetricds and it is working fine.

Now , the problem is:

In the SQL Server table , I have a column defined as `NVARCHAR(20)` which accepts unicode characters like Hindi language characters.

In MySQL,  I have a column defined as `VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Whenever I insert any Hindi character in SQL server, it is not getting replicated in the MySQL table. It is just coming as '???' in MySQL.

Any idea's on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you insert those same Hindi characters directly into the MySQL table?  If no, then you have your answer. If yes, then it could be a conversion issue with Symmetric DS since SQL Server uses UTF-16 Little Endian for XML and `N`-prefixed datatypes.